# Change background color on button click using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, react-redux, jsx

I want to change background on button click but when I click the button the state is empty because of that i am not able to change background color

```
import React,{Component} from "react" 
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'pink', 'purple']

class ChangeBagroundColour extends Component {
state= {
    colour:""
}

handleColour= e => {
    var random = colors[Math.floor(colors.length*Math.random())]
    this.setState({colors:random})
    console.log( this.state.colour,random)
}
render() {
return(
  <div>
      <div>
    <b>Project 1:change baground colour</b>
      </div>

      <div style={{backgroundColor:this.state.colour}}>

        <button  onClick={this.handleColour}>Click me</button>
      </div>
  </div>
)
}
}

export default ChangeBagroundColour
```

Comment: include your state in the constructor and make sure you bind handleColour there as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your setState you have colors instead of colour.

```
this.setState({colour:random})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is in setState you are giving wrong state variable name. It should be

```
this.setState({colour:random})
```